# Selecting user specific records for logged in user using multiple tables PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables one called users and one called tv shows. Im storing the name of the user in a variable called username by doing. The users table holds the user_id PK, username, password and the tv shws table stores the tv_id PK, user_id FK, TV Show Name

```
$username=$_SESSION['username'];
```

i want to be able to display all the tv shows for the specific user that has logged in and im guessing i would need to show all the results for the user id assigned to the user that has logged in because the user_id in the tv shows table is a foreign key of the primary key user id in the users table.

Code:

```
$user = "SELECT user_id FROM users where username='$username'";

if(!$rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tv shows WHERE user_id='$user'")) {
```

When i run this code i get "cannot select table"

Comment: SELECT user_id FROM users where username='$username'  JOIN tv shows ON user_id_id='$user' ?

Comment: This does not work. Cannot select table.

Comment: SELECT user_id FROM users  JOIN tv shows ON user_id_id='$user' where username='$username' and now ?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: user

Comment: Well you have to have variable value to get this query to work. Check why $user is not defined and what is the value of it, and put user in curly braces {$user}

Comment: Before publishing this application read about SQL injection (it's security issue).

Comment: Now it says cannot display table.

Comment: This does not make any sense, if you want to get some correct answers post some more relevant code , we can not guess why you query doesent work based on information you gave us

Comment: SELECT username,user_id FROM users as a JOIN tv shows as b ON b.user_id_id=a.user_id  where a.username='$username' -->> how about now ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM tv_shows where user_id=(SELECT user_id FROM users where username="'.$username.'")';
```

Comment: any error did you get?and can you please provide the sample data so we can figure it out what is wrong?And please check hat which username you try to log in is presented on database or not

Comment: http://cwstudios.co.uk/code.txt there is my code now with your query i cant seem to select the table.

Comment: Where is your code where you storing the value of username to `$_SESSION`

Comment: $username=$_SESSION['username']; that? the username variable works because it says logged in as John. when you are logged in.

Comment: @ChristopherWard Sorry just a mistake in my code i have updated my answer please paste the updated query and see if it works

Comment: it still says cannot select table.

Comment: @ChristopherWard May be it's something wrong with your `database.php` file which is not able to connect to the database or it's table check it manually try to debug with every step.

Answer (score 1):

okay ,try this:

```
<?php
$user = musql_query("SELECT * FROM users where username='$username'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($user);
$userid = $result['user_id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tv shows WHERE user_id=".$userid;
$get_tv = mysql_query($sql);
$make_array = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_tv);
 print_r($make_array);
?>
```

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as a better design, you can have user_id in your  $_SESSION.. so that you can avoid unnecessary  query...

Here the problem could be due to  Single quote ... So please escape  your Single quote ..

Thanks

Comment: Now it says "no records found"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT username,user_id 
FROM users as a 
JOIN tv shows as b ON b.user_id_id=a.user_id 
WHERE a.username='{$username}'
```

Answer (score 0):

managed to figure it out myself with help from Tornado

```
if(!$rs = mysql_query("$query2")) {
$query2 = 'SELECT * FROM tv_shows where user_id=(SELECT user_id FROM users where username="'.$username.'")';
```